# Using "det" command in Matlab to find the determinant of indentity matrix

Tags: matlab

When I create a 3 by 3 identity matrix and try to find the determinant of it, here's what I get: K = eye(3)

K =

```
   1              0              0       
   0              1              0       
   0              0              1
```

> > det(K)
> >     Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

What does this error mean, and how can I fix this?

Comment: you probably assigned `det` to a variable at some point. `clear det` and try again.

Comment: Also I hope you have a good reason to be calculating the determinant of an identity matrix using Matlab...

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to call `det` on the identity matrix when it's simply 1.  That's a known property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix - *"... It follows that the determinant of the identity matrix is 1 and the trace is `n`."*.  Here `n` refers to the number of rows/columns of the matrix.  Nevertheless, see the duplicate question for more details.  As noted by @pragmatist1, you probably declared a variable called `det` and you are overshadowing the function with the variable name.